The Iwasawa decomposition of $GL(2,\mathbb C)$
On  the post (The Iwasawa decomposition of $\text{GL}(2,\mathbf R)$) people said that $\operatorname{GL}(2,\mathbb R)$ has a Iwasawa decomposition of the following form
$$\begin{bmatrix}
    \cos\theta & -\sin\theta\\
\sin\theta &\cos\theta
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    r &0\\
0 &s
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    1 &x\\
0 &1
\end{bmatrix}$$
I was wondering if there was a similar result for the $\operatorname{GL}(2,\mathbb C)$. Probably one would need to allow some of the coefficients to be complex numbers and maybe the rotation matrix gets replaced by a unitary matrix. But at this point I am just guessing because I do not know the theory. So if you don't know the answer a good source to read up on this would also be appreciated.
Any other decomposition of $\operatorname{GL}(2,\mathbb C)$ matrices which contains a diagonal matrix would also be very helpful.

There is no need to invoke complicated theories like Iwasawa decomposition in such a simple case, this is just Gram-Schmidt. You can orthonormalize a basis on $\mathbb{C}^2$ with respect to the canonical hermitian product, so you get a decomposition with unitary matrices.

As @CaptainLama says this is just Gram-Schmidt orthogonalisation. Also known as the QR-decomposition although that is often used specifically to refer to the real version but the process is identical (and you would need to decompose $R$ into diagonal and unipotent parts to be exactly the same as what you gave, but this is easy). The Iwasawa decomposition was invented as a generalisation of this.

The commentors were almost right.
We can QR-decompose $G=UR$ (see \url{https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/2105/2105.04089.pdf}
with $U$ unitary and $R$ upper triangular matrix. Note that we can write $U=D_1 R_x D_2$ for $D_i$ diagonal and $R_x$ the rotation by $x$.
On the other hand we can decompose $R$ into a diagonal and a (scaled) Jordan-block matrix
$$R=\begin{bmatrix}
    r & t\\
0 & s
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
    r &0\\
0 &s
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    1 &x\\
0 &1
\end{bmatrix}$$
where $x=t/r$ (note $r,s\neq 0$, since $\det(G)\neq0$).
So in the end it is $$G=D_1R_x\tilde{D_2} \begin{bmatrix}
    1 &x\\
0 &1
\end{bmatrix}$$
with $$\tilde{D_2}=D_2\begin{bmatrix}
    r &0\\
0 &s
\end{bmatrix}.$$
